# Facing difficulty to pass an array as argument to solve an IVP ODE using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp (distinct scenario)

Tags: python, keras, scipy, ode

I have been trying converge a sine wave to 'amplitude 0' by implementing a neural-network model that predicts the sinusoidal data. The predicted data is substracted from a controller afterwards which is supposed to give me that 0 amplitude.

I want to converge this blue sinusoidal line to zero

[image]

The problematic part of the code is the following one:

```
# Define a new function to subtract Td_pred from Tc
def odefcn2(t, x, Td_pred):
    x1, x2 = x

    Amp = 1
    P   = 110
    Td  = Amp*np.sin(2*np.pi/P*t)

    m = 2
    kd = 3
    kp = 5

    if (t<110):
      Tc2 = - kp*x1 - kd*x2
    elif (t>110):
      Tc2 = - kp*x1 - kd*x2 - Td_pred   # subtract Td_pred from Tc

    return [x2,
            (Tc2_vals + Td)/m]

# Solve the ODE using odefcn2
sol2 = solve_ivp(odefcn2, [t[0], t[-1]], x0, args=(Td_pred, ), t_eval=t, rtol=1e-5, dense_output=True, method='RK45')
x2 = sol2.sol(t)
```

I am getting error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

for the code line

```
sol2 = solve_ivp(odefcn2, [t[0], t[-1]], x0, args=(Td_pred, ), t_eval=t, rtol=1e-5, dense_output=True, method='RK45')
```

The previous part of the full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Solve the IVP ODE
def odefcn(t, x, m, kd, kp):
    x1, x2 = x
    Tc1 = - kp*x1 - kd*x2
    Amp = 1                 # amplitude of sine wave
    P   = 110               # period of sine wave
    Td  = Amp*np.sin(2*np.pi/P*t)
    return [x2,             # x1' = x2
            (Tc1 + Td)/m]   # x2' = (Tc + Td)/m

tstart = 0
tfinal = 220
t      = np.linspace(tstart, tfinal, 10*tfinal+1)
x0     = [1, 0]             # initial value

sol = solve_ivp(odefcn, [t[0], t[-1]], x0, t_eval=t, rtol = 1e-5, args=(2, 3, 5), dense_output=True, method='RK45')
x = sol.sol(t)
plt.figure(1)
plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')
plt.plot(t, x.T)
plt.grid(color='darkgrey', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.5)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.legend(['x1', 'x2'], shadow=True)
plt.title('2nd-Order System')
plt.show()

# Build the NN model
m = len(t)
n = (m - 1)//2

x_train = np.transpose(x)
x_train = x_train[n:]
x_train = x_train.reshape([-1,2])
x_train.shape

Amp      = 1      # amplitude of sine wave
P        = 110    # period of sine wave
Td_train = Amp*np.sin(2*np.pi/P*t)
Td_train = Td_train[n:]

Td_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
Td_model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(200, input_shape=(2,1), activation='tanh'))
Td_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
Td_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
Td_model.fit(x_train, Td_train, epochs=200, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

# Get predicted values 
Td_pred = Td_model.predict(x_train)   # 2D array with shape (1101, 1)
```

My guess is that `odefcn2` is expecting a 1D array while my prediction data, `Td_pred` is a 2D array. The code line that causes this should be `Tc2 = - kp*x1 - kd*x2 - Td_pred` where I am substracting the predicted value from the controller. If I use a single value like `Td_pred[0]`, then I can run the code but the sine wave does not converge to 0, since I am not providing the full predicted data set. I tried reshaping `Td_pred` to 1D array but then the error message goes somewhat like the array is bigger than expected - this should be due to the same `Tc2` code line I mentioned above. Another way I had tried is using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` but that did not converge the sine wave to amplitude 0; rather went to around -5 with noise present.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to be subtracting the value of Td_pred that applies to the specific `t` in question. At any given time, the controller can only be doing a single correction to the value, and you need to represent that. Given that Td_pred is computed in advance, you could look at the `vectorized` option of `solve_ivp`

Comment: That will not help. Apart from making all arguments have arrays of floats where previously there were only floats, and the return value having the same change, `vectorized=True` does nothing for explicit solvers, and for implicit solvers this capability for multi-point evaluation is only used to compute the Jacobian via divided differences. /// You need to either use `Td_model.predict(x)` inside the ODE function or a properly set-up interpolation over a 2D grid, `interp1d` is definitely the wrong function.

Comment: Yes, `vectorized=True` indeed did not work to resolve the issue I was facing. I was, afterwards, working on making the prediction inside the `odefcn2` as well. Thank you so much for kindly replying. I will update once I successfully make the changes.

Comment: @LutzLehmann you're right, I was thinking Td_pred had all the predictions it needed in advance but obviously that's not how solve_ivp works